# Values not inserted in SQL Server DB using ASP.NET WebService

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I am fairly new to programming and just started out with WebService using ASP.NET C# in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. I also downloaded KSoap2 into Android Studio and plan to insert user data into SQL Server DB via the WebService. However, nothing happened. It would be great if you all could take a look at my code and give me feedback as to what is wrong. Thank you all!!

Here is my code for ASP.NET WebService:

```
[WebMethod]
public Boolean InsertUser(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password)
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.UserData(firstName, lastName, email, password) VALUES('" + firstName + "', '" + lastName + "', '" + email + "', '" + password + "')", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return true;
}
```

And here is my code in Android Studio:

```
public class TestCreateAcc extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvS;
EditText etFN, etLN, etE, etP, etCP;
Button btnSub;
String firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPwd;
String displayText;

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/InsertUser";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "InsertUser";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.1.86:53877/Service.asmx";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_create_acc);

    tvS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvS);

    btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(  new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            etFN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFN);
            etLN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLN);
            etE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etE);
            etP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etP);
            etCP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCP);

            firstName = etFN.getText().toString().trim();
            lastName = etLN.getText().toString().trim();
            email = etE.getText().toString().trim();
            password = etP.getText().toString().trim();
            confirmPwd = etCP.getText().toString().trim();
            if(firstName.isEmpty() && lastName.isEmpty() && email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty() && confirmPwd.isEmpty())
            {
                tvS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvS.setText("Fields cannot be left empty!!!");
                tvS.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            }
            else if(!confirmPwd.equals(password))
            {
                tvS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvS.setText("Passwords do not match!!!");
                tvS.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            }
            else
            {
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}

class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        tvS.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);

            PropertyInfo FirstName = new PropertyInfo();
            FirstName.setName("firstName");
            FirstName.setValue(params[0]);
            FirstName.setType(String.class);

            PropertyInfo LastName = new PropertyInfo();
            LastName.setName("lastName");
            LastName.setValue(params[1]);
            LastName.setType(String.class);

            PropertyInfo Email = new PropertyInfo();
            Email.setName("email");
            Email.setValue(params[2]);
            Email.setType(String.class);

            PropertyInfo Password = new PropertyInfo();
            Password.setName("password");
            Password.setValue(params[3]);
            Password.setType(String.class);

            request.addProperty(FirstName);
            request.addProperty(LastName);
            request.addProperty(Email);
            request.addProperty(Password);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            httpTransport.debug = true;
        try{
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String res = response.toString() + "\n";
            res += httpTransport.requestDump + "\n" + httpTransport.responseDump;
            return res;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            return ex.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        displayText = "Success!!";
        tvS.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        tvS.setText(displayText);
        Intent register = new Intent(TestCreateAcc.this, DriverLicenseActivity.class);
        startActivity(register);
    }

}
```

Thank you!! :)

EDIT: I am using and actual Android Device and these are the errors I faced:

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://mobilesystemservice.com refused
returning data cannot be null!
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1

Comment: any error? if you can specify that, then it will easy solve...

Comment: Ahhh thanks, I will add it in :)

Comment: where did you encounter this error? before calling the service?

Comment: @JericCruz After I ran the App on my phone, I filled up the user info and when I click Submit button...

Comment: @Justin456 where are you getting your `params` in `doInBackground` method?

Comment: @JericCruz I don't know tbh, I find the code from various website and just implemented it. I know this is wrong to do but I am very new to this and rushing for a deadline so I just decided to wing it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are getting any values from the `param` parameters. But what you can do is check first put all your code inside a `try-catch` block, then check if you got any values from `param`, then just set the parameter as a simple string.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{   
    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
        //add properties to SOAP object
        //http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.html#addProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
        request.addProperty("firstname", "");
        request.addProperty("lastName", "");
        request.addProperty("email", "");
        request.addProperty("password", "");

        int increment = 0;
        //use foreach to avoid out of bound index
        foreach(String p : params)
        {
            if (p != null)
            {
                //set properties to soap object
                //http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/KvmSerializable.html#setProperty(int, java.lang.Object)
                switch(increment)
                {
                    case 0:
                        request.setProperty(increment, p);
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        request.setProperty(increment, p);
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        request.setProperty(increment, p);
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        request.setProperty(increment, p);
                    break;
                }               
            }
            increment++;
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        httpTransport.debug = true;

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        String res = response.toString() + "\n";
        res += httpTransport.requestDump + "\n" + httpTransport.responseDump;
        return res;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.toString();
    }
}
```

Just based it in [this document](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject.html#addProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

Hope this will help you.

`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Will try it and update you on the results!